# Windows Server 2012 Standard: Remote Access

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2012

Next week I'll be updating an old Windows Home Server machine at home to Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition, and I had a couple questions regarding the features/recommended usage:

1. Is the Web Access piece exclusive to the Essentials version?  Is there a way to manually set this up through IIS in the Standard edition?
2. What is the recommended setup for remotely accessing the machine?  Setting up a VPN?  Would the standard remote desktop be fine?
3. Kind of a silly question, but is there a standard sub-domain name people use for remote access?  vpn.domain.com? ra.domain.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows Server](http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/windows-server-2012) 2012 Standard is a system that provides power to many of the biggest datacenters as well as small businesses worldwide. It has many new features compared to the previous incarnations of the system. Many of the new added features bridge the gap between the server program and new technologies in virtualization and cloud computing. However, with any new product, there are certainly questions that crop up from users. Learning from these questions below can help make all users of this service understand the ins and outs a bit better.

•   Is the Web Access piece exclusive to the Essentials version? Is there a way to manually set this up through IIS in the Standard edition? – This piece is included in Standard and Essentials. You can set it up manually through IIS if you prefer to utilize a role-based installation. You choose this when installing the program. If you chose to install through IIS, you will need to tweak your system a bit compared to installing automatically.

•   What is the recommended setup for remotely accessing the machine? Setting up a VPN? Would the standard remote desktop be fine? – The feature that activates this is called Access Anywhere. This gives you several options for remote access and monitoring your VPM. You set this up using the Access Anywhere Wizard—this is located within the general setup options. A side note, you will need to connect through a domain name you own or purchase through the program.

•   Is there a standard sub-domain name people use for remote access? vpn.domain.com? ra.domain.com? You have the opportunity to choose whichever subdomain you prefer. One of the more common options, and recommended by Microsoft itself is using remote.domain.com

http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/windows-server-2012

Comment: Please don't tell me you just copied and pasted this content.  If you did then you need to cite your source, I say this, because your url is not that source.